# Installation of Orthofinder with conda fails

Tags: package, homebrew, conda

I tried installing orthofinder like this:

```
conda install -c bioconda orthofinder
```

But it returns the following:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

What is going on?

I am using conda 4.9.2 installed using Homebrew.

I also tried with a newer version of conda and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Got solved using the zsh shell. I have no idea why but it worked. If someone knows please let me know.